# Execute Hana stored proc with input parameters in ssrs

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, odbc, hana

I cannot seem to get a HANA Stored Procedure to work with input parameters in SSRS by passing parameters via CALL:

Actuaaly my problem is either SSRS or the ODBC driver is having a problem sending/receiving the parameter value.

Other attempts at syntax: call "sp_getdata"() , call "sp_getdata"(?) , call "sp_getdata"(regid) , call "sp_getdata"(@regid)

None of these worked.

If I call the procedure with a hard coded value i.e. call "sp_getdata"(5) - it works.

Again, if the stored procedure has no parameters it works fine.

Can anyone give me any real direction on this issue. A sample of the correct syntax or a step by step example would really be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `hana`, but if it works with no parameters, then handle the filters in the `SSRS` report after the `dataset` is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the syntax in the Dataset Expression from the Parameter instead of letting SSRS insert the parameter `call "sp_getdata"(?)`

Use the Expression in the Dataset's Command Text box.

```
="Call " & CHR(34) & "sp_getdata" & CHR(34) & "(" & Parameters!REG_ID.Value & ")"
```

The resulting text passed to the server would be (with X for the number):

```
Call "sp_getdata"(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Hannover Fist for for your immediate response. Its working fine now. Could you please help me with multiple parameters! For example, call "sp_get_data(x,y).

Comment: @RajShankar - for multiple parameters you would just add the comma as text `& "," &` and then you parameter. `="Call " & CHR(34) & "sp_getdata" & CHR(34) & "(" & Parameters!REG_ID.Value & "," & Parameters!Y.Value & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work by setting the Dataset query to text with a format such as :
CALL DBNAME.SPROCNAME (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

In the Parameters tab of the Dataset, you add multiple parameters each named ?, mapped to a Parameter Value.